# Finding the modulo with GAS ARM assembler

Tags: arm, modulo, gnu-assembler

I'm attempting to find the remainder in GAS assembler on an ARM processor. Looking that the arm documentation it seems to have this instruction, but I can't seem to make it work using gas. Anyone know if this is valid, and what the syntax is?

```
mov r3, [r9] MOD #2
```

I'm basically wanting to load register 3 with the modulo from division of the contents of register 9 by 2.

Previously I wrote a separate subroutine doing the subtraction and calculation myself, but the arm website seems to show this as a valid instruction.

https://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/a51/a51_op_mod.htm

Answer (score 1):

The `MOD` you're looking at is an operator in the assembler; it can be used to compute the `MOD` function of constants at assembly time, so that you can use the result as another constant.  It is not a machine instruction, and is of no use in computing things for values that are not known until run time.

Computing a remainder mod 2 is very easy; simply find the logical AND with the number 1.

```
and r3, r9, #1
```

If using Thumb, you need two instructions:

```
movs r3, #1
ands r3, r9
```

For a divisor `b` which is not a constant power of 2, finding `a mod b` is harder.  You take advantage of the fact that `a mod b = a - ((a/b)*b)`.  Use `SDIV` to find the quotient `a/b`, then `MLS` to multiply it by `b` and subtract from `a`.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give that a go. :)

Comment: In general mod with any power of 2 can be done by ANDing the number 1 less.  For example x % 32 == x & (32-1).